# Google Data Studio - datetime shows only date

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a Google Sheet containing datetime and present it like this: `10/28/2018 1:00:00`

In Google Data Studio, my column is set to `Date (YYYYMMDD)` but all I see in the table is the date without the time.

[image]

How could I show the date and the time together?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just change the format of the data to

> Date Hour (YYYYMMDDHH)

?